# WPF - Radio button, how to move focus after selection?

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

For the following buttons:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Group1"
             IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsYes,
                                 Converter={StaticResource InverseBool},
                                 FallbackValue=True}"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="Group1"
             Content="_Yes"
             IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsYes,
                                 FallbackValue=False}"/>
```

When keyboard operated and hitting Y or N to select the option, how to move focus to the next control? Other than code behind

Comment: **You can't do this without code behind**. Do you need help with the code behind?

Comment: Yes, I can do it with code behind, but since I am trying for a MVVM system, I was looking for other options

Comment: Using the MVVM doesn't mean that you can't use code behind. Code behind still belogs to the View, and is responsible to bind the View to the ViewModel when xaml can't do that because of its intrinsic limitations (think about calling some method like `InitializeComponent()`: you can't do that in xaml!).
Create an event handler for the `KeyUp` event and the `Checked`/`Click` event. In the event handlers, set the `IsYes` property on the VM. And call `Focus()` on the next element.

I can be wrong, but I think that a concept like "Focus" is to be handled on the View, not on the ViewModel.